# Loading BigQuery tables from large pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, parquet

I am trying to load a relatively large `pandas` dataframe `df` into a Google BigQuery table `table_ref` using the official python `google-cloud-bigquery` client library.

So far I have tried two different approaches:

1) load the table directly from the dataframe in memory

```
client = bigquery.Client()
client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_ref)
```

2) save the dataframe to a parquet file in Google Cloud Storage at the uri `parquet_uri` and load the table from that file:

```
df.to_parquet(parquet_uri)
client = bigquery.Client()
client.load_table_from_uri(parquet_uri, table_ref)
```

Both approaches lead to the same error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Resources exceeded during query execution: UDF out of memory.; Failed to read Parquet file [...]. This might happen if the file contains a row that is too large, or if the total size of the pages loaded for the queried columns is too large.

The dataframe `df` has 3 columns and 184 million rows. When saved to parquet file format, it occupies 1.64 GB.

Is there any way to upload such a dataframe into a BigQuery table using the official python client library?

Thank you in advance,

Giovanni

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to upload the large df to BigQuery by splitting it into a few chunks and loading-appending each of them to a table in BigQuery, e.g.:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
for df_chunk in np.array_split(df, 5):
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df_chunk, table_id, job_config=job_config)
    job.result()
```

Comment: What would you do if you wanted to replace the table, not append to it? Seems like you'd need to first issue a 'DROP TABLE' query, followed by this iterative write, which isn't the most elegant solution.

Comment: You could just change the `job_config.write_disposition` field from `WRITE_APPEND` to `WRITE_TRUNCATE` for the first iteration of the loop and then stick with the `WRITE_APPEND` for the remaining iterations.

Comment: That'll do pig, that'll do. +1

Answer (score 2):

if your parquet file is already loaded on Google Cloud Storage, you can load directly into BigQuery, without a python script:

```
bq load \
--source_format=PARQUET \
dataset.table \
"gs://mybucket/00/*.parquet","gs://mybucket/01/*.parquet"
```

where:

- `mybucket` is the bucket you loaded the parquet file.
- `dataset.table` is your table

In this way BigQuery detects automatically the schema.

BigQuery supports the following compression codecs for data blocks in Parquet files:

- Snappy GZip
- LZO_1C
- LZO_1X

You can read more at this link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the approach you recommend is equivalent to my second approach (which is just a python wrapper around that same code you posted), so it produces the same error. Nevertheless, it pointed towards the right direction, that is to split the dataframe in more chunks and load each of them separately to BigQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Parquet is columnar data format, which means that loading data requires reading all columns. In parquet, columns are divided into pages. BigQuery keeps entire uncompressed pages for each column in memory while reading data from them. If the input file contains too many columns, BigQuery workers can hit Out of Memory errors.
If you think about increasing the alocated memory for queries, you need to read about Bigquery slots.